# What is this thing on the leaf of a Highbush blueberry (Vaccinium corymbosum) bush near a pond on Long Island, NY?

Tags: identification, fungus, insects, rust

My first thought was some kind of insect eggs, but then it seemed reminiscent of some kind of fungal fruiting body.

[image: Eggs or fungal fruiting body]

Comment: most likely the remains of insect eggs - whatever was in them has already hatched and gone...the leaf itself, under magnification appears to have whitish grey deposits over it, would have been interesting to see the underside of that particular leaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out they are Assassin bug (Reduviidae) eggs